# Two questions in the 'Real and Complex Analysis, Rudin'

Tags: real-analysis

I have two questions about the Exercises in the 'Real and Complex Analysis, Rudin'.

p. 72, #7
For some measures, the relation $r<s$ implies $L^r(\mu)\subset L^s(\mu)$; for others, the inclusion is reversed; and there are some for which $L^r(\mu)$ does not contain $L^s(\mu)$ if $r\neq s$. Give examples of these situations, and find conditions on $\mu$ under which these situations will occur.

In the Exercise #5, (c) on page 71, the case for $L^s(\mu)\subset L^r(\mu)$, $0<r<s$ is given. And I think #4 gives the case for which $L^r(\mu)$ does not contain $L^s(\mu)$ if $r\neq s$, right? For the first case, please give me any examples or hints.

Next,

p. 72, #10
Suppose $f_n\in L^p(\mu)$, for $n=1, 2, 3,...$, and $\|f_n-f\|_p\rightarrow 0$ and $f_n\rightarrow g$ a.e., as $n\rightarrow \infty$. What relation exists between $f$ and $g$?

If $1\leq p\leq \infty$, then we can use Theorem 3.12; Cauchy sequence in $L^p(\mu)$ has a subsequence which converges pointwise a.e. So this case is quite easy. However, if $p<1$, then I cannot proceed at all. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: It's better to make your questions self-contained. Include the text of the exercise itself instead of referring to page numbers. Also, don't group unrelated exercises into one question.

Answer (score 1):

In the second problem $f=g$ $a.e$. For this i think prove $0=\int_X |g-f|^p$. If A is the set with $\mu (A^c)=0$ and $f_n \to g$ $\forall x \in A$, then $$\int_X |g-f|^p=\int_A |g-f|^p=\int_X lim_{n \to \infty} |f_n-f|^p \leq lim_{n \to \infty} \int_A |f_n-f|^p \leq (\lim_{n \to \infty} ||f_n-f||_p)^p=0.$$

The first inequality is due to Fatou´s Lemma.